# SAS VARLEN equivalent in python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sas, sas-macro

VARLEN is a function in SAS.

VLENGTH returns the compile-time (allocated) size of the given variable(column).

I need to know if there is any equivalent function or logic in pandas which give how much memory a field in a column is allocated.

Answer (score 0):

There is https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html size. This returns the size of the current dataframe or series if you call it on a column.